# how to call a function when selection is made in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning JavaScript.  I am doing a very simple code of generating random strings of different sizes.

[Here][1] is the link to my codepen code.  My question is currently, it displays the two sample countries, if the user selects one of the countries, I would like to be able to call a function.  How do I do that?

```
 `[1]: https://codepen.io/yared/project/editor/AaoGBP/#0`
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. You can easily find the answer to this question by just searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add onclick events to your country text nodes. [codepen](https://codepen.io/k88lawrence/pen/NgypGb)

in your html:

```
<a id= "australia" onclick="doStuff()" href="#"> Australia </a>
```

in your js:

```
function doStuff() {
  alert("stuff")
}
```

replacing "alert("stuff") with the stuff you actually want to do.

Comment: Thank yo @k88lawrence

Comment: I used your suggestion.  I'm running into different issue.  When I pass the length, it doesn't seem to recognize it.  Currently the alert displays blank.  I used alert to output the length, and it shows 0.  I'm still using the same [https://codepen.io/yared/project/editor/AaoGBP/] in codepen.